# How to save a JSONObject in onSaveInstanceState?

Tags: android, save, restore

I have a problem with JSONObject because I don't know how to save it.
I don't want to load it from file every time, because afterwards the JSONObject will be changed and also it seems a waste of resources to load the file each time the activity resume. How can I do it?

```
private JSONParser jParser;
private JSONObject jObj;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        jParser = new JSONParser();
        setjObj(jParser.getJSONFromFile(this));
    }
    else {
           // savedInstanceState.get(jObj);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    // outState.put(jObj); 

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Comment: You can put a String of the json in the outState (json.toString()). Then you can convert the String to the JSONObject when needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

// Insert

```
savedInstanceState.putString("myJSON", myJsonObject.toString());
```

// Read

```
try {
        String jsonString = savedInstanceState.getString("myJSON");
        JSONObject myObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```